# Why is square root of binomial square simplification not correct?

Tags: graphing-functions

I had a function:

$$\frac{\left(x^3-3x\right)}{\left((x^2+2x+1)^{\left(\frac{1}{\left(2\right)}\right)}\right)}$$

I noted that the it can be re-written as:

$$\frac{\left(x^3-3x\right)}{x+1}$$

Because it is root of a square of a binomial, but I do not understand why the graphs of the first and the second are different for $x < -1$

Why is this simplification wrong?

For the graphs refer to the below link:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wlfwjujrtv

Comment: It is $$\frac{x^3-3x}{|x+1|}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue arises simply because
$$\sqrt{(x+1)^2} = |x+1|$$
and $x+1 \neq |x+1|$ when $x<-1$.

Comment: It is clear now, I often forget this, thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac { \left( x^{ 3 }-3x \right)  }{ \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+2x+1 }  } =\frac { x\left( x-\sqrt { 3 }  \right) \left( x+\sqrt { 3 }  \right)  }{ \sqrt { { \left( x+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }  } =\frac { x\left( x-\sqrt { 3 }  \right) \left( x+\sqrt { 3 }  \right)  }{ \left| x+1 \right|  } =\begin{cases} \frac { x\left( x-\sqrt { 3 }  \right) \left( x+\sqrt { 3 }  \right)  }{ x+1 } ,x+1>0 \\ -\frac { x\left( x-\sqrt { 3 }  \right) \left( x+\sqrt { 3 }  \right)  }{ x+1 } ,x+1<0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Are you sure of your factorization? $x^3 - 3x = x(x^2 - 3) = x(x - sqrt(3))(x + sqrt(3))$

Comment: Oh,my stupid i missed $3$

Comment: No problem, I had myself made such a simple error by forgetting the modulo and even asked this question about it :)